# Does the Intel Core i7-7700 run cooler than the i7-7700k

Tags: cpu, cooling

The [specifications of the Intel Core i7-7700](https://ark.intel.com/products/97128/Intel-Core-i7-7700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) state that it has a TDP of 65W. [The data sheet of the Core i7-7700K on the other hand](https://ark.intel.com/products/97129/Intel-Core-i7-7700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_50-GHz) says that that processor has a TDP of 91W, which would mean that it would run much hotter.

Why is this the case? To my knowledge the only difference is the open multiplier for overclocking on the K-version. Are those TDP values both measured at the stock overclock? Is there another difference that I am missing?

I am asking, because I want to build a small ITX PC and a TDP difference of 21W is quite immense. More so than the price difference.

Comment: you considered the different base clock ( [3.6 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/products/97128/Intel-Core-i7-7700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) vs [4.2 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/products/97129/Intel-Core-i7-7700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_50-GHz) ), right?

Comment: @flolilolilo Ah, I did not. So if I underclock the 7700k, it will also have a TDP of 65W?

Comment: That's a question that never occured to me. As the architecture is most likely the same, I would think that this should be possible - if the multiplicator can be set below the standard value and they didn't fiddle with the voltages (perhaps someone with more insight can answer that). What's your use-case? Is there a reason why you consider the K-CPU, though you don't want to use its capabilities? (I'd include that in the initial question.)

Comment: But isn't the voltage the thing that decides the thermal outup of the CPU?

Comment: It's a combination of the clock speed, the number of cores (and other transistors if we're pedantic) and the voltage. AFAIK, VCore even decreases with increasing clock speeds (though VCore isn't the only voltage of course).